# Atom And Anaconda (windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

I want to use Atom as a IDLE and manage my libraries on Anaconda.

I have both my Python libraries (numpy, pandas, etc) and Python 2.7 interpreter in my `C:\Anaconda2`.

Previously I was using Jupyter notebook to write my scripts and managing my libraries in Anaconda. 
I want to transition to using atom as a IDLE. 
Once I tried running my Python scripts on Atom. 
It seems as if Atom is not seeing where my packages are. But somehow I have no problem running a regular Python script.

```python
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
for x in list1:
    print x
```

This script works perfectly.

Problems comes when I have to call `numpy` or other `scipy` libraries.

```python
import numpy as np
list2 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
for j in list2:
    print j
```

Below is the error I get on Atom:

```
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe
2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
['C:\\Users\\AhmedAskar\\Desktop\\atom', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Anaconda2', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AhmedAskar\Desktop\atom\numbers.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .numerictypes import object_
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 87, in <module>
    import numbers
  File "C:\Users\AhmedAskar\Desktop\atom\numbers.py", line 9, in <module>
    tt =np.array([[7,9],[4,3]])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe
2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
['C:\\Users\\AhmedAskar\\Desktop\\atom', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Anaconda2', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg']
[Finished in 0.461s]
```

Comment: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen

Comment: sorry correct. atom the text editor. i want it to interphase it with my package from anaconda env

Comment: The error that you show has code that isn't present in your sample. Please create a self-contained minimal example that demonstrates this error and post all of the code here. It looks like you've duplicated a package (called numbers) that NumPy expects. Try renaming that file (`C:\Users\AhmedAskar\Desktop\atom\numbers.py`) to something else

Comment: i renamed it with generic name testttt.py still same error